# Por que o código não está funcionando?

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

Eu quero, por meio de um *script* (*Javascript* puro e simples), alertar após o *click* em um determinado *link* (da classe "**sair**") o seguinte: "Você está saindo do site".

Meu *script* está assim:

```
window.document.querySelectorAll('.**sair**').onclick = function aviso() {
     alert('Você está saindo do site.');
};
```

A classe "**sair**" está no trecho de marcação HTML, abaixo:

```
<p><a href="http://www.google.com.br" title="www.google.com.br" class="botao sair">Google</a></p>
```

Quando aciono o *link*, ele não alerta absolutamente nada.

**Observação**

Tentei com o *script*:

```
window.document.getElementsByClassName('sair').onclick = function aviso() {
    alert('Você está saindo da página.'); 
 };
```

E, também não funcionou.

O que está errado?!

Desde já, grato,

*Alexandre Soares*

Comment: Você tá chamando a classe `botao sair` no HTML (`class="botao sair"`), e usando `.sair` (`.'sair').onclick`) no javascript. Pelo menos um dos problemas deve ser este (testei aqui mudando e mesmo assim não abriu). Mas daqui a pouco alguém aparece com a solução. :-)

Comment: Obrigado, Gustavo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se tens mais do que um link, vejo que estás a usar o querySelector**All**, então tens de usar um ciclo `for` para adicionar o oscultador de eventos a cada elemento. Isto porque o `querySelectorAll` dá uma lista de elementos (tipo *Array*).

Algo assim:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('.sair');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].addEventListener('click', aviso);
}

function aviso(e) {
    alert('Você está saindo do site.');
};
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f8mr69jt/

Podes também usar a tua sintaxe `links[i].onclick = aviso;` ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f8mr69jt/1/))

Se tiveres somente um elemento tens de usar o `querySelector` (sem o *All*) e [aí o teu código já funciona](http://jsfiddle.net/f8mr69jt/2/), ou seja não precisas do ciclo `for`.

Comment: É verdade, tem mais de um *link* no *site*, sim. Tentei o seu *script* e nada aconteceu também, amigo. Substitui o "var links = document.querySelectorAll('.sair');" por "var links = document.getElementsByClassName('sair');", infelizmente, sem sucesso. Obrigado, assim mesmo, por sua sugestão, Sérgio. Engraçado que em teoria está tudo certo. Inspecionei com o "*Developer Tools*" do Chrome e ele não apresentou nenhum erro na construção dos *scripts*. Vai saber...!...

Comment: @AlexandreSoares não estás a usar mesmo asteriscos aqui `'querySelectorAll(.**sair*');*"`pos não?

Comment: Tens esse script onde na página? no `<head>` ? `<body>`?

Comment: Não usei os asteristicos, não. Estava tentando formatar o comentário, apenas. O *script* está local, no HEAD, mesmo. Pois estou testando.

Comment: @AlexandreSoares aí está o problema! Coloca no fundo da página, antes do `</body>`

Comment: Agora funcionou! Mas, e se eu quiser pôr o *script* em um arquivo externo, irá deixar de funcionar?

Comment: @AlexandreSoares nesse caso faz assim: `window.onload = function() { /* o teu código aqui */ }`, e dessa maneira o script vai correr quando a página tiver carregado. Senão esse `querySelectorAll` ainda não encontra o HTML. Testa assim no `head` também que vai funcionar.

Comment: @AlexandreSoares vou embora agora, se a resposta resolveu p problema podes marcar a resposta como aceite se quiseres.

Comment: Agora está OK! Muito grato, Sérgio! Você é um crânio! Está perfeito! Forte abraço,  *Alexandre*